# What does the differential $d\Sigma_{ab}$ means when integrating over a two-surface?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, notation, integration

In the paper $[1]$, Bardeen integrated an identity between Killing vectors and the Ricci tensor. I'll reproduce the calculation and explain my question in the following.

Consider then the identity,

$$K^{a;b}\hspace{0.5mm}_{b} = -R^{a}\hspace{0.5mm}_{b}K^{b},\tag{1}$$

Where $K^{a}$ is the Killing vector components, and $R^{a}\hspace{0.5mm}_{b}$ the Ricci tensor components. Then, integrating $(1)$ over a hypersurface $S$ and transferring the volume on the left to an integral over a $2$-surface $\partial S$ bounding $S$ $[1]$, we have:

$$\int_{\partial S} K^{a;b} d\Sigma_{ab} = - \int_{S} R^{a}\hspace{0.5mm}_{b}K^{b} d\Sigma_{a}.\tag{2}$$

**So, my question is: what is the form of the elements $d\Sigma_{ab}$?**

> I have done courses on tensor calculus and I've been studying relativity and differential geometry for some time, but I've never encountered this notation for $d\Sigma_{ab}$ before.
>
> Cleary what is happening here is the stokes theorem; roughly, in this case, it is the divergence theorem. Now, I know that for a vector field $A^{a}$ we have:
>
> $$\int_{V} A^{a}\hspace{0.5mm}_{;a} dV = \int_{\partial V = S} A^{a}u_{a}dS.\tag{3}$$
>
> Where $dV$ is the volume element. Therefore, $(2)$ is just the generalization of $(3)$. Given a second order tensor $T^{ab} := K^{a;b}$ , we have:
>
> $$\int_{S} \nabla_{b}T^{ab} d\Sigma_{a} = \int_{\partial S} T^{ab} v_{b}d\Sigma_{a} := \int_{\partial S} T^{ab} d\Sigma_{ab} = - \int_{S} R^{a}\hspace{0.5mm}_{b}K^{b} d\Sigma_{a} \tag{4}.$$
>
> Then, if my reasoning is correct the form of $d\Sigma_{ab}$, is $d\Sigma_{ab} = v_{a}d\Sigma_{b}$. But, I don't know if this is correct.

---

$[1]$ J.M. Bardeen, B.Carter, S.W.Hawking. *The Four Laws of Black Hole Mechanics*. 1973. equation $(5)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In three-dimensional calculus, we often write $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{n} \mathrm{d} S$ to mean the infinitesimal element of directed area. $\mathrm{d} S$ is an element of area, while $\mathbf{n}$ is an unit vector normal to this infinitesimal area. $\mathrm{d} \Sigma_{ab}$ is the same idea, but we now have a two-dimensional element of area within a four-dimensional manifold, so we actually have two normal vectors, hence two indices.

Alternatively, you can think of that differential as simply meaning that you are integrating with respect to the volume form induced on $\partial S$

Comment: but, my formula (4) is ok?

Comment: @M.N.Raia Not really. Notice that, in the Stokes theorem you wrote, $\mathrm{d} \Sigma_{a} = u_a \mathrm{d}S$, not $\mathrm{d} \Sigma_{a} = u_a \mathrm{d}V$. Hence, there is no reason to expect $\mathrm{d} \Sigma_{ab}$ to be a tensor product between a finite vector and $\mathrm{d} \Sigma_{ab}$. The differential on $S$ is not equal to the differential on $\partial S$.

Comment: So, do you have any reference of the stokes theorem using index notation?

Comment: @M.N.Raia I can't remember a reference by heart, but I guess GR textbooks might have it stated somewhere. In any case, the notation is irrelevant. I suggest trying to write the integral over $S$ in your preferred notation and then just using Stokes in your preferred notation